# Please try reformatting. Location error in Play console form

Tags: google-play, google-play-services, google-play-console

To recover my lost jks file, I need to submit my new JKS pem file to google support in their appeal form. After filling the form and submission. Error occured under the location "Please try reformatting". Kindly Help. thanks

I have tried another browser, another PC and refresh my pages but nothing happen to this error.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have been a bug in Play Console that is now fixed. I was able to submit the form yesterday, on the 25th of December.